# assetic:dump and error 404 JS files not found

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic, uglifyjs

I've been using assetic:dump for a while. However, since we changed the server of our application we have been experiencing strange errors. Actually, the JS files generated by assetic:dump cannot be found (404). And what is strange is that this bug depends on the server I'm using. On the production server, the JS are available on app.php but not on app_dev.php. On the tests server, the JS are available on both app.php and app_dev.php. On the development server, the JS are neither available on app.php nor on app_dev.php. It's for sur an environment issue. However, I cannot find where the problem is.

My configuration:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:
        - MyBundle 
    ruby: %path_ruby%
    node: %path_node%
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:
            bin: %path_sass%
            apply_to: "\.scss$"
        lessphp:
            file: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php"
            apply_to: "\.less$"
        uglifyjs2:
            bin: %path_uglifyjs2%
        assets:
            back_js:
            inputs:
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/jquery/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/transition.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/alert.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/button.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/carousel.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/collapse.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/modal.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/popover.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/tab.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/affix.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/Braincrafted/Bundle/BootstrapBundle/Resources/js/bc-bootstrap-collection.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/js/plugins.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/js/jquery.minicolors.js"
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/js/jquery.minicolors.min.js"
            - "@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.countTo.js"
            - "@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/backend.js"
        output: js/headooback.js
```

After app/console assetic:dump and app/console assetic:dump --env=prod, I have:

On the html/app_dev.php a link like this

```
<script src="http://bugs.com/js/505da13_back_1.js?2"></script>
```

On the html/app_dev.php a link like this

```
<script src="http://bugs.com/js/505da13_1.js?2"></script>
```

And on my web folder

```
js/back.js
```

I have already tried to uninstall nodejs and uglifyjs and then to reinstall both of them. I'm sure that the path for their bin are correct. I also disabled the javascript-common.conf of Apache in case it was searching the js in the wrong folder. What else can I check? Or what else can influence the generation of the js ? I have no errors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a "app/console as:in" (assetic:install)?

Comment: Hi Ray, there's no assetic:install command. However, I do assets:install and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

This often happens with assetic if you don't clear cache after changing its settings. Try doing that: `rm -r app/cache/*` and then run the dump again. This could also explain difference between servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to say that I tried many times to clear the cache on the different servers. This is not the problem.